# which image has class, change src JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, attr

I want to change src for image which has class 'activeLittle'

```
$('#sliderInfoBoxImages img').hasClass('activeLittle').attr('src', 'some.jpg');
```

error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'attr'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('#sliderInfoBoxImages img.activeLittle').attr('src', 'some.jpg');
```

[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean result inidicating whether the element has the passed class or not... which does not have the method `attr()` so you get the error

Answer (score 0):

The function [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) will return a boolean value. It wont return any elements. By the way you have to use `element with class/Id selector` to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
$('#sliderInfoBoxImages img.activeLittle').attr('src', 'some.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$img = $('#sliderInfoBoxImages img');
if($img.hasClass('activeLittle')){
    $img.attr('src', 'some.jpg'); 
}
```